# Enable Perforce job creation for each issue that is created on JIRA

Tags: jira, perforce, jira-plugin, fisheye, atlassian-fisheye

I followed the next guide:

https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/FISH/JIRA+FishEye+Plugin+2.5.3+-+Perforce+Job+Integration

and successfully created a link between Perforce and JIRA.

I did manage to create a Perforce job on JIRA issue creation while selecting that option with the p4 job custom field.

What I cannot configure is a creation of a job automatically for each issue for a specific project as described in the next section:

```
Creating Jobs for ALL issues in a project

Another method of creating jobs (without the need to configure custom fields) is to set the Always create jobs for issues in this project flag in the project-level Perforce administration screen."
```

I can't find that flag for some reason.

Can anyone assist with screenshots or any other helpful information?

Eventually what I need to do is that for each issue that is created in JIRA a job should be created in Perforce.

Thanks in advance,

Max.

Comment: You may wish to give P4DTG a try, as an alternative solution:

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it.

Comment: Nope, this is not a bad solution but we want to make if with Fisheye.
Thank you!